# parse two mapping file and extract mapping for a particular clientId

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have two mappings file like this as shown below:

**primary_mapping.txt**

```
{1=[343, 0, 686, 1372, 882, 196], 2=[687, 1, 1373, 883, 197, 736, 1030, 1569], 3=[1374, 2, 884, 737, 198, 1570], 4=[1375, 1032, 1424, 3, 885, 1228], 5=[1033, 1425, 4, 200, 886]}
```

**secondary_mapping.txt**

```
{1=[1152, 816, 1488, 336, 1008], 2=[1153, 0, 817, 337, 1489, 1009, 1297], 3=[1, 1154, 1490, 338], 4=[1155, 2, 339, 1491, 819, 1299, 1635], 5=[820, 1492, 340, 3, 1156]}
```

In the above mapping files, each `clientId` has primary and secondary mapping. For example: `clientId 1` has `343, 0, 686, 1372, 882, 196` primary mapping and `1152, 816, 1488, 336, 1008` secondary mapping. Similarly for other `clientIds` as well.

Now in my shell script, I want to print `PRIMARY_MAPPING` and `SECONDARY_MAPPING` but only for `clientId` passed from the command line to the shell script. For example: In below example, I am passing `1` so it should print out all the primary and secondary mappings for `clientId 1`. Similarly if we pass 2 then it should do that for 2 as well.

```
./print_mapping.sh 1
```

Below is my shell script but I am not sure on how to parse those two files and extract mapping for a particular `clientId`:

```
# extract individual mappings from each of those two files given a particular clientId and assign it to `PRIMARY_MAPPING` and `SECONDARY_MAPPING` array.

for pm in "${PRIMARY_MAPPING[@]}"
do
echo $pm
done

for sm in "${SECONDARY_MAPPING[@]}"
do
echo $sm
done
```

Comment: too bad you have almost-but-not-quite JSON. Valid JSON would make this easier.

Comment: Bash is a terrible language for parsing custom formats. Try changing the strings to JSON and process them with `jq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#/bin/bash
for n in {1..5}
do
  echo "$n:"
  for f in primary-mappings.txt secondary-mappings.txt
  do
    sed -r "s/.*\b$n=\[([^]\]+).*/\1/" $f
  done
echo
done

1:
343, 0, 686, 1372, 882, 196
1152, 816, 1488, 336, 1008

2:
687, 1, 1373, 883, 197, 736, 1030, 1569
1153, 0, 817, 337, 1489, 1009, 1297

3:
1374, 2, 884, 737, 198, 1570
1, 1154, 1490, 338

4:
1375, 1032, 1424, 3, 885, 1228
1155, 2, 339, 1491, 819, 1299, 1635

5:
1033, 1425, 4, 200, 886
820, 1492, 340, 3, 1156
```

From the `for f in primary-mappings.txt` part, you can extract the loop and declare it as function, which takes the n as parameter `n=$1` to only output single clientIDs.

#### assignment to array

To answer the question in the comment, assign the inner values to an array. For working with arrays, you should read something like [this Bash-FAQ chapter](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005). Here is a concrete example

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfiles=(primary-mappings.txt secondary-mappings.txt)

declare -a arr

mappingsByClientID () {
  id=$1 # 1 to 5 
  file=${mapfiles[$2]} # 0 to 1
  arr=($(sed -r "s/.*\b${id}=\[([^]\]+).*/\1/; s/,/ /g" $file))
  echo "${arr[@]}"
}

# assign output of function to an array
pri3=($(mappingsByClientID 3 0))
snd4=($(mappingsByClientID 4 1))
```

#### explanation:

Don't forget to use a shebang. Store the filenames in an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfiles=(primary-mappings.txt secondary-mappings.txt)
```

Define a function, which expects ID and - for primary or secondary 0 or 1:

```
mappingsByClientID () {
  id=$1 # 1 to 5 
  file=${mapfiles[$2]} # 0 to 1
  arr=($(sed -r "s/.*\b${id}=\[([^]\]+).*/\1/; s/,/ /g" $file))
  echo "${arr[@]}"
}
```

The sed-line not only picks the part from `2=[687, 1, 1373, 883, 197, 736, 1030, 1569]`, and reduces it to the values, separated by commas, but removes the commas, because that's what bash like to be an array assignment to look like, `a=(x y z)`.

Usage:

```
# Testing
# assign output of function to an array
pri3=($(mappingsByClientID 3 0))
snd4=($(mappingsByClientID 4 1))
# access whole array
echo "whole arr pri 3: ${pri3[@]}"
echo "whole arr snd 4: ${snd4[@]}"
# access by literal index (starting at 0)
echo "first el. in arr pri 3: ${pri3[0]}"
# arraylength with #, index of last is ((len-1)):
len2nd=$((${#snd4[@]}-1))
# access by array index 
echo "last  el. in arr snd 4: ${snd4[$len2nd]}"
```

Of course it would be handy to work with 3dim arrays like in C-like languages like this:

```
# doesn't work, 3Dim-Arrays
for n in {1..5}
do
  for i in 0 1
  do
    # doesn't work:
    # arr[$n][$i]=($(mappingsByClientID $n $i))
    # doesn't work either
    # arr${n}${i}=($(mappingsByClientID $n $i))
  done
done
# echo arr[3][0][2]
# echo arr30[2]
```

But there is no support for this, and the different lengths of the arrays make it hard to implement some trickery.

Comment: There is one thing I wanted to check with you on this - let's say if for a particular `clientId` there is no primary or secondary mapping then I want to log a message and exit out of the shell script with non zero status code. In your suggestion is it possible to do that?

Comment: Comments aren't a good place to introduce new questions. Please ask a new question but feel free to take the code from here. You might set a link there to this question and add an inviting link to the new question here. Then you have again the possibility to choose again your favorite answer. Many users may answer so you might get a better answer and/or a faster answer.